# What does Titanium use Interpreter or Compiler

Tags: android, ios, titanium-mobile

Can someone make me clear whether Titanium mobile uses Interpreter or Compiler to build application for Android and iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the good article which covers some of inner workings on Titanium mobile - http://titaniumninja.com/post/10559549700/fastdev-for-ios-how-it-works/

Based on it: "the JavaScript files that compose an application are not compiled to native code. Instead they get interpreted by a JavaScript engine"